# How do I deserialize a Dictionary<string, string[]> in C#?

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I have a dynamic JObject that maps a string key to an array of strings. But I'm having trouble deserializing it. I get an uncaught runtime exception each time.

`var mapStringToStrings =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string[]>>(payload.Map);`

This is what the JObject contains

```
   {{
     "c637c0bf-42ec-4f33-a679-5a220260db8e": [
       "dfe7514d-1e42-4c01-ac48-4557e4e34eb3"
     ] 
   }}
```

And this is the error:

`The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string[]>>(string)' has some invalid arguments`

Help?

Comment: What exactly is `payload.Map`?  Is it a `string`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a dynamic JObject won't deserialize nicely if it's a complex object -- I resolved simply by calling .ToString() on the payload.map before passing it to the deserializer.

**Works:**

`var mapStringToStrings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string[]>>(payload.map.ToString());`

Answer (score 3):

Your JObject is not valid JSON because it has an extra pair of `{}` around it. The following is valid JSON that deserializes as `Dictionary<string, string[]>`:

```
{
  "c637c0bf-42ec-4f33-a679-5a220260db8e": [
    "dfe7514d-1e42-4c01-ac48-4557e4e34eb3"
  ]
}
```